# How levels.fyi is encoding the API response?

Tags: javascript, security

I noticed something interesting while navigating through [levels.fyi](https://www.levels.fyi/t/software-engineer?countryId=197&country=197). When I visited a page that displayed a list of salaries, the API response that returned the salary data appeared to be hashed. For example, if you call:

```
GET https://api.levels.fyi/v3/salary/search?countryIds[]=197&offset=10&limit=50&sortBy=offer_date&sortOrder=DESC&jobFamilySlug=software-engineer
```

The response appears like this:

```json
{
    "payload": "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"
}
```

I believe that both the frontend and backend have a secret key for hashing and decoding the response data. If possible, I would like to implement something similar on my own API and understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Their implementation**

You are correct that there is a secret key being used to encrypt and decrypt a JSON payload. Well, not so "secret" because the key is in the JS downloaded to the browser. I'd presume they do this to make scraping the content of the site via its API a bit more difficult.

The encrypted payload is sent encoded as Base64 (so the first thing in getting the content is to turn it back into an unencoded series of bytes).

If you look in the `commonUtils.js` file from the site, you'll find a function that does the decryption (just search for `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt`). The process for decryption is to hash a "secret" string using MD5 then derive a key from part of the hash. This key is then used to AES-128 decrypt the payload that was decoded. The plaintext from this is a zlib deflated stream.

So the final step to get a standard JSON response is to inflate the stream, and the result is readable.

```
{
 "total":1000,
 "hidden":0,
 "rows":[
  {
   "uuid":"b0b851a1-ba7b-49ab-8190-6bf8aec0aa21",
   "title":"Engineer",
   "jobFamily":"Software Engineer",
...
```

**How you could do the same thing**

First, select a key that you will use to encrypt your payload. Provide the key to the browser in some way accessible to your JS code running in the browser.

When you want to send a payload, compress the payload as a whole (that site uses zlib deflate, which is sensible from a performance and suitability perspective). Then encrypt with your "secret" key (they do some derivation that loses some security of the key against actual cryptographic attack, but they aren't securely handling the key so this doesn't really matter). Finally, Base64 encode and send in a response (they put this in a JSON response, which is also a good idea).

In the browser, reverse all that: take the JSON payload; decode from Base64; establish your key however you need to; decrypt the decoded payload using the key; uncompress the result, and you have your response to return to the calling function.

levels.fyi seem to use a static string for their encryption key, but you could theoretically generate new keys regularly if you liked.